# D3.js csv to html table

Tags: javascript, d3.js

table (successfully) generated by D3.js from csv file loads at the bottom of body and below scripts tags. Hence I cannot select table for adding id, classes and more

I tried adding a table tag in the html with id and classes I need and forced the append to that but I got the newly generated table INSIDE the table tag in html.. and so still not selectable.

```
var tabulate = function (data,columns) {
    var table = d3.select('#myTable') // this is the solution
 // var table = d3.select('body').append('table') this was before the solution
      var thead = table.append('thead')
      var tbody = table.append('tbody')


      thead.append('tr')
        .selectAll('th')
          .data(columns)
          .enter()
        .append('th')
          .text(function (d) { return d })

      var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
          .data(data)
          .enter()
        .append('tr')

      var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
          .data(function(row) {
              return columns.map(function (column) {
                  return { column: column, value: row[column] }
            })
        })
        .enter()
      .append('td')
        .text(function (d) { return d.value })

    return table;
  }
  d3.csv('data/Inventory.csv')
  .then(function(data) {
    const columns = ['Environment','vCluster','HostName','HostModel','BiosVersion','BiosDate','OSversion','HBAadapter','HBAdriver','HBAfirmware','NICadapter','NICfirmware','NICdriver','HPiLOversion','HPiLOfirmware','OAfirmware']
    tabulate(data,columns)
  });
```

I need that the generated table is properly created as an element and so it is selectable and workable.

Comment: There is a typo in your code. Second line, there is a dot between select and the parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks @BrunoFenzl ... rectified that... problem remains of course..

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your problem properly. Your table is not being added inside the body tag?

Comment: the table is  generated fine and it's added automatically to the end of the body tag. Right before </body>
Hence after the script tags and as a consequence I cannot select it as it loads after all scripts. The table is generated dinamically by D3. I have no table  tags in the body

Comment: Have you tried `var table = d3.select('#mytable');`? Where 'myTable' is the ID of your table you already created

Comment: many thanks  @BrunoFenzl ! I did but I was insisting on the append on that line and it didn't work. While your suggestion did the trick! Thanks  again

Comment: don't know how to give you marks or credits for this.. I rectified my code with your suggestion anyway

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I added my comment as answer if you want to mark it as answer. I would also suggest you add a comment with your edited code in a separate paragraph or code block so future viewers know the difference before and after the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try just selecting your existing table instead of selecting AND appending it to the DOM:

`var table = d3.select('#mytable');`

Hope it helps.